# Group by across multilple joins

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, group-by

Following Query returns me data with multiple values for column `FM.FaultIDMSTR`, I want to eliminate duplicate and take only one value and display the other data along that value.

```
Select TOP 1000 
  FH.AtmKey,F.FAULTDESC,FH.FAULTSTARTTIME,FH.FAULTENDTIME,FM.FaultIDMSTR
From FAULTS_HISTORY FH, FAULTDEFS F, FAULTMAP FM 
where FH.FaultID = F.FAULTID
and F.FAULTID = FM.FaultID
and FH.AtmKey in ('11487676154140993')
```

[image]

The condition to eliminate the duplicate would be based on larger value derived from column `FH.FAULTSTARTTIME`.

I am not sure how to achieve this level of grouping with multiple joins in place, here's my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**ranking function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) [`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    Select TOP 1000 
      FH.AtmKey,
      F.FAULTDESC,
      FH.FAULTSTARTTIME,
      FH.FAULTENDTIME,
      FM.FaultIDMSTR,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FM.FaultIDMSTR
                        ORDER BY FH.FAULTSTARTTIME DESC) AS RN
    From FAULTS_HISTORY FH
    INNER JOIN FAULTDEFS F ON FH.FaultID = F.FAULTID
    INNER JOIN FAULTMAP FM ON F.FAULTID = FM.FaultID
    where FH.AtmKey in ('11487676154140993')
)
SELECT 
  AtmKey,
  AULTDESC,
  FAULTSTARTTIME,
  FAULTENDTIME,
  FaultIDMSTR
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

This will give you the rows with maximum of `FH.FAULTSTARTTIME` for each `FM.FaultIDMSTR`, if you want to group by another column put it in the `PARTITION BY` column.

**Note that:** Try to avoid the old `JOIN` syntax, and use the ANSI-92 syntax, see this:

- [**Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: thanks for quick response, I understand the idea here but executing query as whole gives following errors:                           Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "FH.AtmKey" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The multi-part identifier "F.FAULTDESC" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The multi-part identifier "FH.FAULTSTARTTIME" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The multi-part identifier "FH.FAULTENDTIME" could not be bound.Seems the reference in Outer Select is not working

Comment: Are you sure that the table `FAULTS_HISTORY` contains the column `AtmKey` and `FAULTSTARTTIME` and `FAULTENDTIME`? Ensure that the tables aliases and the columns names are correct, I just got these names from your query.

Comment: @user2385057  This error from the last SELECT from CTE . There are no `FH`,`F` in this query so just use `SELECT AtmKey,  FAULTDESC,  FAULTSTARTTIME,  FAULTENDTIME, FaultIDMSTR.... `

Comment: @valex Aha, thanks, this is my fault, just copy and paste, updated thanks